# GWT disable MultiSelectionModel

Tags: java, events, gwt

In GWT I have a grid with `MultiSelectionModel`. In some cases I need to disable this `MultiSelectionModel` and enable it again.
I tried `NoSelectionModel` like this:

```
protected void disableSelectionOnGrid() {
    NoSelectionModel<TOUi> model = new NoSelectionModel<TOUi>();
    grid.setSelectionModel(model);
}
```

but when I pass from `NoSelectionModel` to `MultiSelectionModel` I have the following exception:

> Uncaught Exception: com.google.gwt.view.client.NoSelectionModel cannot
>   be cast to com.google.gwt.view.client.MultiSelectionModel

Comment: Which method of which class are you trying to pass a NoSelectionModel to? Please specify in the question.

Comment: When do you need to enable/disable the action, end user must be able to do it somehow or?

Comment: I have two cases: ViewMode and EditMode; when end user open modal in ViewMode I should disable selection on grid and viceversa